# how to load data into hive table if the delimiter itself present in the data?

Tags: hive

I am loading data to hive table which contains comma in the data itself.

```
input file:emp.csv 

101,deepak,kumar,das
102,sumita,kumari,das
103,rajesh kumar das

output :
id  name
101 deepak kumar das
102 sumita kumari das
103 rajesh kumar das
```

When I created the below hive table and loaded the data, data is not coming properly:

```
 create external table hive_test(
 id int, name string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/hive_demo';

load data local inpath '/home/cloudera/hadoop/hive_demo/emp.csv' overwrite into table hive_test;

hive> select * from hive_test;
101 deepak
102 sumita
103 rajesh kumar das
```

So I created below table, but it is giving error.

```
create external table hive_test1(
id int,
name string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(
"separatorChar" = ",",
"quoteChar" = "'",
"escapeChar" = "\,")
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/hive_demo';
load data local inpath '/home/cloudera/hadoop/hive_demo/emp.csv' overwrite into table hive_test1;

select * from hive_test1;
Failed with exception 
java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The separator, quote, and escape characters must be different!
```

How can I load the data to the Hive table?

Comment: Your input file is a mess: without quotes around the 2nd field, there is no way to define a proper CSV mapping (and that's not specific to Hive). Option 1: rebuild that file properly, either with a different separator e.g. tab or semicolon, or with quotes around text fields. Option 2: fix the existing file with e.g. `sed` to e.g. replace first colon char with another "separator" char. Option 3: maybe the "regex serde" can be used as a workaround in Hive but that would be a lame fix IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Providing solution below assuming:

- You always need to extract only 2 cols from the csv.
- The first col is a numeric, the 2nd col extends till the end of the line after the first ',' character.
- You need to replace any ',' character in `name` column with spaces.

#### Use RegexSerDe to define table and load

```
create external table hive_test(
id int, name string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "input.regex" = "^(\d+),(.*)$" -- 2 regex groups as per assumption
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
LOCATION '/path/to/table';
LOAD data local inpath '/path/to/local/csv' overwrite into table hive_test;
```

#### Replace the ',' in `name` column by space

```
create table hive_test1 as 
select id, regexp_replace(name, ',', ' ') as name
from hive_test;
```

Then, on `select * from hive_test1`, you obtain below:

> 101   deepak kumar das
>   102   sumita kumari das
>   103   rajesh kumar das